# pandas multiindex(date, time) time display issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
date,time,price
2014-07-01  09:15:00.500000 100
2014-07-01  09:15:01        200
2014-07-01  09:15:01.500000 300
2014-07-01  09:15:02        400
2014-07-01  09:15:02.500000 500
```

I set MultiIndex:

```
df.set_index(['date','time'])
```

The result is:

```
    date        time          
2014-07-01  33300000000000    100
            33360000000000    200
            33420000000000    300
            33480000000000    400
            33540000000000    500
Name: price, dtype: float32
```

**Why time is converted into numbers?**

**How to display like HH:MI:SS.SSS**

BTW, I have used `loc` method to select date like this:

```
df.loc['20140701':'20140702']['price']
```

How to select row with multiple index?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I am using 0.16 and it is not converting the format of the date index

Comment: pd.__version__ is '0.14.1'. Mac OS X 10.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I have updated pandas's version from 0.14.1 to 0.16.2.
It's OK!

Thanks @kathirmani